# HTML and CSS formatting picture to be bottom bar on website

Tags: html, css, image

I have a simple webpage with a main section that is 85vh and a "floor" which is 15vh. The floor element contains an image which I want to look like the floor of the page. It has a checkerboard pattern that fades to white and looks like a floor.

My current CSS is working pretty well, however, the problem I'm having is when the user makes the window skinny (less than 800px or so in width), the floor image stars to become really small and it doesn't look good and it doesn't look like a floor anymore.

What changes should I make to the CSS to make the image in the floor element looks like the "floor of the page", no matter what the width or height of the window is? It should probably be centered and adapt to the window width, but not get smaller than 1920px or so the floor looks the same size at any window width, but gets cropped automatically to adapt to the page width.

https://jsfiddle.net/z7w41vd5/

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.main {
  height: 85vh;
}

.floor {
  height: 15vh;
  min-width: 1920px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.floor img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>

  <div class='main'>

  </div>

  <div class='floor'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/VuLVv68.png'>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a background image instead of an `<img />` and you'll be able to control it the way you want to.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.main {
    min-height: 85vh;
}

.floor {
    min-width: 1920px;
    min-height: 15vh;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/VuLVv68.png) bottom center;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='main'></div>
    <div class='floor'></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could make it the background of the `<body>` and remove the floor element from your html entirely.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/VuLVv68.png) bottom center no-repeat;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='main'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated